# Trying to run the function socket_recvfrom but it returns an error: socket_recvfrom(): unable to recvfrom [0]: The operation completed successfully

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I am running a function: @socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $buf, 8192, 0, $from, $port);

but this returns an error saying:

> socket_recvfrom(): unable to recvfrom [0]: The operation completed successfully.

Anyone who has an idea about this? What does this mean?

OS: Windows

PHP: 5.3

Morten

Comment: Why does not the @ operator supress the error?

Comment: Can you post a bit more code / more details?

Answer (score 0):

It might mean that the socket is non-blocking and there was no buffered data available when the function was called, or that the socket received an out-of-band message. Or that the socket has not been created correctly in the first place.

The [0] after the "unable to recvfrom" makes me think that this might be the resource id for the socket - which would not be 0 if te socket had been created succesfully.

C.

Comment: It is most likly that there is no data in the buffer.
But why wont the @ operator supress the warning?

I am running the code ina ZEND environment known as php4Delphi (psv).

The PHP engine reports the warning as an error and terminates the script even if I set the error_reporting to E_ALL | ~E_WARNING

..Strange


Morten